# Database entering blank data from Facebook using AJAX Post & PHP

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, facebook

I’m creating a Facebook Canvas game, and up until now I have been hosting it on my laptop at localhost, along with my database which was also hosted locally using phpMyAdmin. I’m now moving both online and have encountered a problem with the database.

When I hosted it locally, I was able to grab details about the player (their Facebook ID, first name, last name, email, gender) and insert that data as a row into my database whenever the player loaded the homepage. This worked without any problems on localhost.

However, since I moved it online, it’s inserting blank fields instead of Facebook data. The online database is connecting correctly, and it will enter other values if I write them directly into the Insert statement in my .php script. I think the problem may be to do with the AJAX post I’m using.

I’m calling a Javascript function `onload` of the homepage, this runs the following piece of code:

```
function getUserDetails() {

FB.login(function(response) {
  if (response.authResponse) {
    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');

     FB.api('/me', function(response) {

     if (response.error) {
       console.log('Error - ' + response.error.message);
     }
     else {
       var userid = response.id;
       var userfirst_name = response.first_name;
       var userlast_name = response.last_name;
       var useremail = response.email;
       var usergender = response.gender;

       $.ajax({
         url: 'scripts/php_scripts/insertuserdetails.php',
         data: {'userid' : userid,
               'userfirst_name' : userfirst_name,
               'userlast_name' : userlast_name,
               'useremail' : useremail,
               'usergender' : usergender},
        type: "POST",
        success: function(response){

                 if(response==1){
                         alert( "Insert worked!");
                         }
                    else{
                       alert( "Insert failed!" );
                              }
                    }
       });
     }
    });
  } else {
    console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
  }
 }, {scope: 'email'});
}
```

And the PHP file it posts to is this:

```
<?php 

session_start();

require_once 'facebook-php-sdk-v4-4.0-dev/autoload.php';

use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookHttpable;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurl;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurlHttpClient;
use Facebook\Entities\AccessToken;
use Facebook\Entities\SignedRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookSignedRequestFromInputHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookCanvasLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookOtherException;
use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
use Facebook\GraphObject;
use Facebook\GraphUser;
use Facebook\GraphSessionInfo;

FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('myappid', 'myappsecret');

$servername = "myservername";
$username = "myusername";
$password = "mypassword";
$dbname = "mydbname";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$userid = $_POST['userid'];
$userfirst_name = $_POST['userfirst_name'];
$userlast_name = $_POST['userlast_name'];
$useremail = $_POST['useremail'];
$usergender = $_POST['usergender'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO player (fb_id, f_name, l_name, email, gender) VALUES 
('$userid', '$userfirst_name', '$userlast_name', '$useremail', '$usergender');";
$sql .= "INSERT INTO bank (fb_id, cb, gb, invite)
VALUES ('$userid', '200', '0', '');";

$result = mysqli_multi_query($conn, $sql);
if ($result) {
   $verify=1;
}
else{
  $verify=0;
}
echo $verify;

mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

I don’t understand why everything is working correctly except for the blank values for the Facebook data (for example, the `‘200’` and `‘0’` are getting inserted correctly). 
Is it possible that the Insert statement is firing before the Facebook data arrives? And if so, how could this be an issue when it's hosted online but not be an issue when it's hosted locally?

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: console your response

Comment: Probably a 3rd party cookies problem.

Comment: Hi @CBroe it looks like you're right! I deleted the cookies and it now works! Thank you! If you'd like to write that as an answer then I'll mark it as accepted. Also, I've been reading up on how to make my code more secure, I need to use parameterized statements, and also separate my database connection from this code. I have been trying to use a separate php connection script and then include it at the top of this code, but I can't seem to get it to work, would you be able to show me an example of how to do that with the above code? Thanks again!

Comment: Hi @noddy thanks for your reply, it appears to be working now after deleting the cookies from my browser.

Comment: Great.. Enjoy your work :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a typical third-party cookies problem.

Canvas apps on Facebook are run inside an iframe, and so the iframe content is considered as coming from a “third party” by browsers, and depending on privacy settings, cookies set from within that iframe might get blocked.

You said deleting your cookies fixed it for you; however, that does not necessarily mean it will work for other users as well, if their browser blocks third-party cookies by default – so you should do some more testing. Users might either have to change their settings to allow such cookies, or you will have to try and not use cookies for your sessions, but pass the session id as a GET or POST parameter with your requests.